# How to .endSale from a contract?

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-deployment

I am writing a smart contract for a token sale.

How can I endSale destroy contract and transfer remaining tokens and accumulated ethers from the sale  to admin wallet ( using truffle commands)?

I have two contracts:

1. StoriToken.sol
2. StoriTokenSale.sol

Code for contract 1

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract StoriToken {
    string  public name = "STori Token";
    string  public symbol = "STOR";
    string  public standard = "STori Token v1.0";
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    event Transfer(
        address indexed _from,
        address indexed _to,
        uint256 _value
    );

    event Approval(
        address indexed _owner,
        address indexed _spender,
        uint256 _value
    );

    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

    function StoriToken (uint256 _initialSupply) public {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
        totalSupply = _initialSupply;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);

        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;

        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);

        return true;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;

        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);

        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= balanceOf[_from]);
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);

        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;

        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;

        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Code for Contract 2

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

import "./StoriToken.sol";

contract StoriTokenSale {
    address admin;
    StoriToken public tokenContract;
    uint256 public tokenPrice;
    uint256 public tokensSold;

    event Sell(address _buyer, uint256 _amount);

    function StoriTokenSale(StoriToken _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenPrice) public {
        admin = msg.sender;
        tokenContract = _tokenContract;
        tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
    }

    function multiply(uint x, uint y) internal pure returns (uint z) {
        require(y == 0 || (z = x * y) / y == x);
    }

    function buyTokens(uint256 _numberOfTokens) public payable {
        require(msg.value == multiply(_numberOfTokens, tokenPrice));
        require(tokenContract.balanceOf(this) >= _numberOfTokens);
        require(tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens));

        tokensSold += _numberOfTokens;

        Sell(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens);
    }

    function endSale() public {
        require(msg.sender == admin);
        require(tokenContract.transfer(admin, tokenContract.balanceOf(this)));

        selfdestruct(admin);
    }
}
```

Thank You in Advance

Comment: In your second contract there is an `endSale()` function. Are you asking how to trigger that function? Or are you asking for advice on how to rewrite it to accomplish something else?

Comment: yes...my question is how i trigger that function on truffle console to endSale and transfer remaining tokens back to admin.